# Dealing with overful vbox in a footnote

Tags: footnotes, warnings, amsart

I'm working mainly with the `amsart` class, and like many academics, I use footnotes quite liberally in my papers. But unlike many academics, I take overful and underful warning quite seriously.

Sometimes I get an overful vbox warning, and tracking it down shows that the fault lies with the footnotes, and normally by a depressing 1.8pt or so. My solution so far was to rewrite some of the text, but this can end up with having to rewrite half a page sometimes. Which seems like taking the warning a bit *too* seriously.

What can I do, then? Is there a way to tell LaTeX to take this into consideration when paginating and maybe push one more line to the next page?

Comment: latex does (should) take the footnotes into consideration, so the question is why isn't that happening here. You can usually avoid overfull hboxes by re-wording the text but normally the vertical extent isn't influenced by the particular wording, unless you are making the paragraph a line shorter?  Given no input it's hard to guess why you are getting overfull hboxes so hard to suggest what to try changing.

Comment: Does it look off when you view the output? If it looks fine, you can always set `\vfuzz=2pt` in the document preamble. As @DavidCarlisle says, without more information (perhaps some images of document pages?) it's hard to offer specific advice.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I meant rewording, rephrasing, or even completely rewriting. Yes. It's hard to give examples, since they only happen in "organic writing", and I am reluctant to post my actual papers here. (Not that it would get stolen, it's just that there's a reason I'm Ink Blot and not my real name.)

Comment: @DonHosek: It's very hard to recognize a 2pt vertical overflow in the comments. When I enable `showframe`, you can see that it cuts through the last line of the footnote, yes.

Comment: @Inkblot there is no need to post any private text, just take your document and cut it down to a one or two page example with the problem, then as it's just the vertical extent that is an issue, replace any (say) five line paragraph by `zz\\zz\\zz\\zz\\zz` and check you get the same overfull box, adjust if not (you may need a descender and have to use `zzy` or whatever it takes, then post the result.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks. I will try it tomorrow (unfortunately, I fixed the latest thing by rewriting a paragraph, so it's not as easy to find such an example, but the paper I'm currently revising has a lot of footnote, so it's probably going to show up again soon).